# Spark/Kafka error after updating Spark 2.4 to Spark 3.1

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I tried to upgrade from Juypterhub using pyspark 3.1.2 (using Python 3.7) using Debian Linux with Kafka from **Spark 2.4.1 to Spark 3.1.2**. Therefore, I also update Kafka from 2.4.1 to 2.8 but this does not seem to be the problem. I checked the dependencies from https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ and it seems fine so far.

For Spark 2.4.1 I used these additional jar in the sparks directory:

- slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar
- unused-1.0.0.jar
- lz4-java-1.6.0.jar
- kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar
- spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.4.3.jar
- spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.4.3.jar

For Spark 3.1.2 I updated these jars and already added some more the other file already existed like unused:

- spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.1.2.jar
- spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.1.2.jar
- spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.12-3.1.2.jar
- spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.1.2.jar
- kafka-clients-2.8.0.jar

I striped my pyspark code to this that works with spark 2.4.1 but not with Spark 3.1.2:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T
from pyspark.sql.utils import AnalysisException
import datetime

# configuration of target db
db_target_url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"
db_target_properties = {"user": "john", "password": "doe"}

# create spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("live1").getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set('spark.sql.caseSensitive', True)

# create schema for the json iba data
schema_tww_vs = T.StructType([T.StructField("[22:8]", T.DoubleType()),\
                           T.StructField("[1:3]", T.DoubleType()),\
                           T.StructField("Timestamp", T.StringType())])

# create dataframe representing the stream and take the json data into a usable df structure
d = spark.readStream \
  .format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
  .option("subscribe", "test_so") \
  .load() \
  .selectExpr("timestamp", "cast (value as string) as json") \
  .select("timestamp", F.from_json("json", schema_tww_vs).alias("struct")) \
  .selectExpr("timestamp", "struct.*") \

# add timestamp of this spark processing
d = d.withColumn("time_spark", F.current_timestamp())
d1 = d.withColumnRenamed('[1:3]','signal1') \
  .withColumnRenamed('[22:8]','ident_orig') \
  .withColumnRenamed('timestamp','time_kafka') \
  .withColumnRenamed('Timestamp','time_source')
d1 = d1.withColumn("ident", F.round(d1["ident_orig"]).cast('integer'))

d4 = d1.where("signal1 > 3000")

d4a = d4.withWatermark("time_kafka", "1 second") \
    .groupby('ident', F.window('time_kafka', "5 second")) \
    .agg(
         F.count("*").alias("count"), \
         F.min("time_kafka").alias("time_start"), \
         F.round(F.avg("signal1"),1).alias('signal1_avg'),)

# Remove the column "windows" since this struct (with start and stop time) cannot be written to the db
d4a = d4a.drop('window')

d8a = d4a.select('time_start', 'ident', 'count', 'signal1_avg')

# write the dataframe into the database using the streaming mode
def write_into_sink(df, epoch_id):
    df.write.jdbc(table="test_so", mode="append", url=db_target_url, properties=db_target_properties)
    pass
query_write_sink = d8a.writeStream \
     .foreachBatch(write_into_sink) \
     .trigger(processingTime = "1 seconds") \
     .start()
```

Some of the errors are:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool2/impl/GenericKeyedObjectPoolConfig
Jul 22 15:41:22 run [847]: #011at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer$.<init>(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:623)
Jul 22 15:41:22 run [847]: #011at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer$.<clinit>(KafkaDataConsumer.scala)
…
jupyterhub-start.sh[847]: 21/07/22 15:41:22 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Jul 22 15:41:22 run [847]: 21/07/22 15:41:22 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = 5d2a70aa-1463-48f3-a4a6-995ceef22891, runId = d1f856b5-eb0c-4635-b78a-d55e7ce81f2b] terminated with error
Jul 22 15:41:22 run [847]: py4j.Py4JException: An exception was raised by the Python Proxy. Return Message: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jul 22 15:41:22 run [847]:   File "/opt/anaconda/envs/env1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 2451, in _call_proxy
Jul 22 15:41:22 run [847]:     return_value = getattr(self.pool[obj_id], method)(*params)
Jul 22 15:41:22 run [847]:   File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 196, in call
Jul 22 15:41:22 run [847]:     raise e
Jul 22 15:41:22 run [847]:   File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 193, in call
Jul 22 15:41:22 run [847]:     self.func(DataFrame(jdf, self.sql_ctx), batch_id)
Jul 22 15:41:22 run [847]:   File "<ipython-input-10-d40564c31f71>", line 3, in write_into_sink
Jul 22 15:41:22 run [847]:     df.write.jdbc(table="test_so", mode="append", url=db_target_url, properties=db_target_properties)
Jul 22 15:41:22 run [847]:   File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 1445, in jdbc
Jul 22 15:41:22 run [847]:     self.mode(mode)._jwrite.jdbc(url, table, jprop)
Jul 22 15:41:22 run [847]:   File "/opt/anaconda/envs/env1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1310, in __call__
Jul 22 15:41:22 run [847]:     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
Jul 22 15:41:22 run [847]:   File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
Jul 22 15:41:22 run [847]:     return f(*a, **kw)
Jul 22 15:41:22 run [847]:   File "/opt/anaconda/envs/env1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
Jul 22 15:41:22 run [847]:     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
Jul 22 15:41:22 run [847]: py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o101.jdbc.
Jul 22 15:41:22 run [847]: : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 200) (master executor driver): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool2/impl/GenericKeyedObjectPoolConfig
```

Do you have ideas what causes this error?

Comment: I think conflict happen between kafka client and commons-pool2 Try adding commons-pool2-2.8.0.jar https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-pool2/2.8.0

Comment: You also should not have kafka-clients or either of the `spark-streaming-kafka` since `spark-sql-kafka-0-10` includes the clients and you are not using Spark Streaming

Comment: Thanks devsh, I already tried commons-pool2-2.10.0.jar but (only) version 2.8 seems to work. Do you want to change your comment to an answer?
Why is there a simple documentation what jars are really needed?

Comment: @tardis Is issue resolved just by addition of commons-pool2-2.8.0.jar fully then only we can put answer to help others?For compatibility issue in library  even well documented project face issue due to  updation in dependent library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As devesh said there was one jar file missing:

- **commons-pool2-2.8.0.jar** that can be downloaded from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-pool2/2.8.0

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this - in my case I was just trying to read Kafka into a stream on Spark 3.0.2 and no matter how I tried to add org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.2, I was still getting the dreaded  Py4J error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError, which usually means version incompatibility.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it resolved following these steps :

- Go to [the main spark-sql maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12/3.5.0)
- Check the compile/provided dependencies :
  [image]
- Click on each dependency(hit the version number) and downland the target jar
  [image]
- Add each jar file to a folder that is visible to spark-master/spark-workers :
  for example in docker-compose you can set :

```yaml
    volumes:
      - ./data/jars:/spark-jars
```

- finally start spark session and address all these jars :

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("spark://spark-master:7077") \
    .appName("Step2_03-Hashtag-Processing") \
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "512mb") \
    .config("spark.executor.cores","1") \
    .config("spark.cores.max", "1") \
    .config("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "Asia/Tehran") \
    .config("spark.jars", "/spark-jars/spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.5.0.jar,/spark-jars/spark-tags_2.12-3.5.0.jar,/spark-jars/kafka-clients-3.5.0.jar,/spark-jars/commons-pool2-2.11.1.jar,/spark-jars/jsr305-3.0.2.jar,/spark-jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.5.0.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()
```